# Using Axios GET with Authorization Header in vue App

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to use axios for a GET request with an API which requires an Authorization header.

here is my current code

My current code:

```
data () {
   return {
      listings: [],
      AuthStr : 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')),
   }
},
created () {
   axios.get(`url`, { 'headers': { 'Authorization': AuthStr } })
   .then((response => {
       this.listings = response.data;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
       console.log(error)
   })
}
```

it shows me 403 error I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to to add header to request.

For a single request:

```
let config = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: value,
  }
}


axios.get(URL, config).then(...)
```

you need to call `data().AuthStr` to get your token there is a typo.

Your created function will be

```
created () {
   axios.get(`url`, { 'headers': { 'Authorization': data().AuthStr } })
   .then((response) => {
       this.listings = response.data;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
       console.log(error)
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

`` axios.get(`url`, { 'headers': { 'Authorization': this.AuthStr } }) ``

Answer (score 0):

You are using `JSON.parse` when getting the value for `AuthStr`. `JSON.parse` returns an object. Try removing it and if you are using the correct Auth token, it should work.